# fuzzy searching with query_string Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

i have a record saved in `Elasticsearch` which contains a string exactly equals to `Clash of clans`

now i want to `search` this `string` with `Elasticsearch` and i using this

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "clash"
    }
}
```

its working perfectly but now if i write

```
"query" : "class"
```

it dont give me back any record so i realize i should use `Fuzzy` searching so i come to know that i can use `fuzziness` parameter with `query_string` so i did

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "clas"
        "fuzziness":1
    }
}
```

but still elasticsearch is not returning anything!
kindly help and i cant use `Fuzzy` query i just can use `query_string`.
Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use the [~ operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_fuzziness) to have fuzzy searching in `query_string`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "class~"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro u r amazing ;)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. however i wonder if there is no other way because I'm passing the query from an HTTP parameter, so i think it can lead me to problems in the future (if the user adds ~ character at the end of the string).

Comment: What if I have "query": `${search}*`? how to use fuzziness ?

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro Did you find the solution to this `${search}*`?

Comment: * and ~ is not supported in the same query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#avoid-widlcards-fuzzy-searches